# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gp'

Tags: modulenotfounderror

I'm attempting to utilize the GaPP package and have followed the installation instructions outlined in the documentation:
"For installation, unpack the file, change into the GaPP directory and install GaPP with: python setup.py install".

However, upon attempting to import modules, such as gp or dgp, from the GaPP package using the command "from gapp import gp (or dgp)," I consistently encounter this error. I would greatly appreciate assistance in resolving this issue.

I tried to use the same command to install gp.py but it seems wrong.